# Does VBScript have Increment Operators

Tags: vbscript

Like Javascript has `++` and `+=` for a increments?

Comment: C# or VBScript? Big difference -- yes, and no.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No. Unfortunately, you have to do:

```
value = value + 1
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the full list of operators is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5a1xhce%28VS.84%29.aspx).

Comment: Ugh vbs is ALL the way retro :(

Comment: @Callat given the answer was written almost 7 years prior to your comment, what do you expect? It was already "retro" then.